Prevent Docker from removing volume content when doing compose up
I'm making an application to store music and have a backend made with ASP.NET that I'm trying to move to Docker
The music is stored in a folder called "data/" next to when I run the docker and contains the music files and a file "info.json" that keep all the metadata
To run my docker I have the following "docker-compose.yml"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
    user: "1000:1000"
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/euphonia/data

However I noticed that everytimes I do docker compose up, all the content of my info.json is thrown back to {}
I heard this could be solved by adding external: true to the volume but I couldn't figure out how to do that with a relative path as I have
How can I do so my Docker still have access to read/write in that file, while keeping its content when I launch it again?

You have a bind mount, not a named volume; the /euphonia/data directory in your container should be exactly the contents of the data directory on your host, and if content changes, you should be able to see it on the host system.  There are no particular options that could be changed here.  Is the container path correct?  How are the files being used?  How do you see that the file is being reset, and what code might do that?

I suspect that you aren't saving your info.json file in the /euphonia/data directory. If it's saved somewhere else, it's part of the container's file system and is deleted when the container is removed.

Following these comments I went back on my code and indeed noticed that what I assumed was an issue with my Docker config was just an issue with my code, thanks
I'm not sure what I should do with this post tho?

If you want, you can write an answer yourself. Or delete the post. Or let it be.
